# Warning: Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not present in the window hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using Vserv complete sdk for addintegeration.I'm calling my adViewController to present my add.if the failed add fails I'm taking to a SplashViewController from my addViewController.But I'm getting this warning
`Warning: Attempt to present <SplashViewController: 0x1dd697b0> on <AdViewController: 0x1dd68690> 
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and not able to navigate to my next view that is SplashViewController..I've tried all the methods below is the code.Could u guys help me out:

**AdViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   if([Util isInternetAvailable])
    {
        //Initializes SDK
       [VservAdManager initializeSDK];

        CGRect frame1;

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            frame1 = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);

        else
            frame1 = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

        vservAdView = [[VservAdView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];

        [vservAdView requestAd:self:@"7825":nil];

        [self.view addSubview: vservAdView];
    }
    else{

        appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.splashViewController;
        [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.splashViewController animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
    else {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
}

- (void)adReceivedNotification:(VservAdView*)vservAd{
    NSLog(@"adReceivedNotification");
}

- (void)adFailedNotification:(VservAdView*)vservAd{
    NSLog(@"adFailedNotification");
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.splashViewController;
    [self presentViewController:appDelegate.splashViewController animated:NO completion:Nil];

}

- (void)adSkipedNotification:(VservAdView*)vservAd{
    NSLog(@"adSkipedNotification");
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.splashViewController;
    [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.splashViewController animated:NO];
}
```

**SplashViewController.h**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self setupMovie];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
    else {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
}

-(void)setupMovie{
    NSLog(@"setup Movie");
    NSString* moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Splash" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL* movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    playerCtrl =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    playerCtrl.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    playerCtrl.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    //  playerCtrl.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        [playerCtrl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    }
    else{
        [playerCtrl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, 320, 240)];
        }

//    [playerCtrl.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2)];

    [self.view addSubview:playerCtrl.view];
    [playerCtrl setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];
    [playerCtrl play];
}

-(IBAction)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(id)sender{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.revealController animated:NO];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.revealController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you presenting view on self if you set the root view of windows to splashViewController?

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.splashViewController;
[self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.splashViewController animated:NO];
```

instead use this

```
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.splashViewController;
[appDelegate.window presentModalViewController:appDelegate.splashViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: if i m to comment the second line. the problem what i face is i wont be able to navigate from my splashviewcontroller to my firstviewcontroller...its goes something like this when i load my application i ll get the add in my adviewcontroller if the add fails..i load the splashscreen which playes a video and then load my firstviewcontroller..if i comment the second line its stuck with the blackscreen when my add fails.if i m to uncomment and when the add fails..it loads the firstviewcontroller without showing the splashviewcontroller video..what i want is to play the video and load the firstvie